# microservices methods granularity

Tags: microservices

I'm building an Mvc application with microservices that retrieve information from the database.

I have a question related the microservices.
I want an entity from database with some property in a page of the application. So I've build the method of the service that retrieve the information.

In another page, i want the same entity but with other properties in addition.

I have two possible way:

1. implement another method that return a new dto
2. Add the properties to the method that already exist.

In the first case i have a new method and a new dto to mantain but any change is possible and under control, in the second one i have a unique dto but with properties not used by the first client pages.

Which is the best "Scholastic" microservices solution ?

Comment: Were do the different properties come from, are the from the same database, same schema, same table?

Comment: Yes they are on the same table, schema and database.

Comment: Is this a school assignment?  Since when is "scholastic" a desirable quality in software development?

Comment: The question has nothing to do with Microservices. Microservices is an architectural style. The "scholastic" of Microservices operates in abstraction layers far beyond from  *how do I support different formats for the same DTO*.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is the same table, schema, and database one method would suffice as the data is all in the same bounded context from a micro-service point of view.  Consider breaking into 2 services if the data is not part of the same bounded context.

I would consider breaking into two methods if the number of properties on the second retrieval is large enough to warrant a 2nd call.  In that case I would make an initial call to fill a "slim" object and then the secondary call to fill the "full" object.  But if there are only a few properties that are different, just make one call.

For example, if the first call retrieved 3 properties and the next call retrieved 5 properties, just one call.

If the first call retrieved 3 properties and the 2nd call retrieved 20 properties, then having 2 separate calls would make sense, whether using micro-services or not.  Also, if the user is always going to get all the data regardless, just one call up front.